# How to Add Remote with Git Gui?

Tags: git, git-gui

I want to push my changes to a folder on a remote server. I can even do a map drive to it.
Wish there was a folder browser (the same as choosing where to create repo) where I can select the server folder I want to push to. Since there isn't I know I have a syntax error here.

[image]

Comment: Can you explain why this is a bad question when you down vote? Or please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding a remote has nothing to do with the physical remote itself. It is only for management of references to remotes themselves.

That being said, it sounds like you want to use Git to deploy to a server. You can use pushing of a branch to attain this. However, you first must have the remote setup via running this on the server

```
git clone --bare //path/to/your/repo /some/dir/on/the/server/.git
```

Now you must add a hook to this repo to fire every time you push to a branch. Within this hook you would:

```
git --git-dir=/some/dir/on/the/server/.git --work-tree=/where/to/deploy/to checkout deployment-branch -- .
```

You'll have to google `git update hook` to get the few lines of code needed to wrap the above line.